# How to use rsync to copy images and dir

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, copy

I am in the middle of merging 2 directories into 1.

```
/competitions/1
/competitions/2
/competitions/3

/gallery/1
/gallery/2
/gallery/3
```

I want to copy all the files in /competitions to /gallery and put them in there respective folders. I can assume that all file names are unique and will not be copied over.

How can I do this with rsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rync -av /competitions/* /gallery
```

should do the trick.